# undestanding csv module delimiter

Tags: python

Hi guys!

I'm currently working with a python csv module and trying to use a '|' delimiter. From what i understand the delimiter is a characted that seperates the values of each column of a table.

What i don't understand is why python keeps putting ';' between the values of each column, not a '|' after i've set the deliminator? Here's an example

```
# Suppose i have an excel table 'example' saved as a .csv file containing a simple table like this:
# Cat | Mouse | Dog

>>> ifile = open('example.csv', 'r')
>>> reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter = '|')
>>> reader.next()
['Cat;Mouse;Dog']  # But shouldn't it be ['Cat|Mouse|Dog'] !?
```

As you can see, each column is seperated by a semicolon, but shouldn't it now use '|' as a column seperator when i changed the delimiter to '|'?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure your CSV file actually has `|` characters in it?  How are you saving it from Excel?  The way it's reading it shows that it didn't find the delimiter at all.  What you want to see is `['Cat', 'Mouse', 'Dog']`.

Comment: If you use a pipe `|` as a deliemiter, its not a CSV (Comma Separated Values).  It'd be a PSV or Pipe Separated Values. =p

Comment: No, my csv file doesn't have any '|' characters in it. I just made an excel file and types the three words : Cat, mouse and dog in 3 seperate rectangles (i dont know how these small rects are exactly called in english, sorry). Am i getting something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
ifile = open('example.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter = ';')
print reader.next()
```

```
['Cat', 'Mouse', 'Dog']
```

Comment: Yes, it works as it produces the output you got. But, i was actually looking for an answer that explained what a delimiter is, as i didn't quite get it in python docs. There aren't any ';' characters in my excel table, why do i have to set ';' as a delimiter and why can't i use for example '|' ?

Comment: @geekkid: now open your .csv file in notepad. Tell me what you see.

Comment: i see a bunch of ';' characters that represent the empty columns in my corresponding excel document. Heh, it kind of makes sense now. When i save the excel file as a .csv file, it automatically seperates every rectangle by a ';'. right ? but what if set the delimiter to '|' then ? doesn't this work ? why ?

Comment: @geekkid: Setting the delimiter in python when reading the file will (obviously) have no effect on which delimiter excel used when it wrote it. The `delimiter` in python has to match the one in the file.

Comment: Ok, that makes sence :d. thank you everyone for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading in from the file you would not expect to see the delimiter in your list, since that is what is used to split the line into separate list elements.  The issue here appears to be that the delimiter in your CSV file is actually ';' rather than '|'.