# Python CSV Delimiter: Separate Cells

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I'm working on understanding how to use the delimiter function with CSV. The code below is what I have so far, but what I am trying to do is to get each item in a separate cell for the CSV file. I  tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405485/undestanding-csv-module-delimiter)...

```
import csv
import datetime
# imports modules

now = datetime.datetime.now()
# define current time when file is executed

how = str(raw_input("How are you doing?"))
why = str(raw_input("Why do you feel that way?"))
scale_of_ten = int(raw_input("On a scale of 1-10. With 10 being happy and 1 being sad. How happy are you?"))
#creates variables for csv file

x = [now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),how,why,scale_of_ten]
# creates list for variables to be written in

f = csv.writer(open("happy.csv","wb"))
# creates f which makes a happy.csv type wb
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
w.writerow([x])
```

I get this error below from running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "journal.py", line 18, in <module>
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

How would I get my inputs into separate cells instead of one?

Comment: As a side note: [`delimiter=','` is already the default](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter), so you don't actually need to do _anything_ here.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to create a csv.writer from a csv.writer; you should include the delimiter argument when making f and just use that.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.writer` expects a file like object.  It looks like you try to create the writer twice.  Try this...

```
import csv
data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f)  # use the file as the argument to writer
    wtr.writerow(data)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Basically f should simply be a file object or fid in my case.You give the writer method another csv.writer object.   The csv.writer first parameter should be a file ID, such as acquired by the open('new.csv','w')

```
fid = open('new.csv','w')
w = csv.writer(fid,delimiter=',')

#write to file
fid.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the 'w' variable, just do this:

```
f = csv.writer(open("happy.csv", "wb"), delimiter=',')
f.writerow([x])
```